# NetBean EJB Client Application failed to build

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

`Distributing C:\Users\JACK WONG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MYUSER_ClientApplication\dist\MYUSER_ClientApplication.jar to [GlassFish Server]
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
C:\Users\JACK WONG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MYUSER_ClientApplication\nbproject\build-impl.xml:985: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)`

This is the error message when I am done to "Clean & Build" every project and deploy the Enterprise Application. Then I go to "Run" Client Application, this is the error I got. I research the internet, I had tried many methods but still can't find the right solution.

ClientApplication:-

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\JACK WONG\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MYUSER_ClientApplication" -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -DforceRedeploy=false run
init:
Week_2_2.init:
Deleting: C:\Users\JACK WONG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Week_2_2\build\built-jar.properties
Week_2_2.deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\JACK WONG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Week_2_2\build\built-jar.properties
Week_2_2.compile:
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\JACK WONG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Week_2_2\build
Copy libraries to C:\Users\JACK WONG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Week_2_2\dist\lib.
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\JACK WONG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Week_2_2\dist\Week_2_2.jar"
Week_2_2.jar:
deps-jar:
compile:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
Building jar: C:\Users\JACK WONG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MYUSER_ClientApplication\dist\MYUSER_ClientApplication.jar
dist:
pre-run-deploy:
Distributing C:\Users\JACK WONG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MYUSER_ClientApplication\dist\MYUSER_ClientApplication.jar to [GlassFish Server]
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
C:\Users\JACK WONG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MYUSER_ClientApplication\nbproject\build-impl.xml:985: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

GlassFish:-

```
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [MYUSER_ClientApplication]
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Specified library jar Week_2_2.jar does not exist: C:\Users\JACK%20WONG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Week_2_2\dist\Week_2_2.jar
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.getAppLibs(DeploymentContextImpl.java:458)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createDeploymentClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:229)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [MYUSER_ClientApplication] : Specified library jar Week_2_2.jar does not exist: C:\Users\JACK%20WONG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Week_2_2\dist\Week_2_2.jar
```

Comment: try closing netbeans and reopening

Comment: I had tried that kind of method. I also tried stop and start the GF service. But the result still the same. :/

Comment: You'll need to post the relevant parts of the server.log, since that's where any error you are encountering is likely to be logged.

Comment: I've update the post.

Comment: your project is calling for a jar Week_2_2 that isn't reference correctly

Comment: So do I need to add the Week_2_2 JAR into the library?

Comment: But I had check my computer, and there is Week_2_2 JAR file over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there are no spaces in your path names. In your case, "JACK WONG" in your path name might the cause of the problem

> "C:\Users\JACK WONG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Week_2_2\dist\Week_2_2.jar".

Romove the spaces and try again